# Numerous 100% Height/Width divs - carousel navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, carousel

I have a webpage that uses 100% widths and heights to achieve a fullscreen image style. However, I would like these divs to be side-by-side, and when I click a button it shifts to the next or previous slide. How do you think I could achieve this?

Here's the carousel code:

```
<div class="page-carousel">

    <div class="page page-01" style="background: url(images/01.jpg);">

        <div class="page-text">

            <h1>Headline</h1>
            <h2>Subheader</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="page page-02" style="background: url(images/02.jpg);">

        <div class="post-text">

            <h1>Headline</h1>
            <h2>Subheader</h2>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.page-carousel{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.page{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: no-repeat bottom center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend: http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/

Comment: @Ranman This might be what I fall back to if I can't get something simpler. When I tried it, I found a lot of styling that I can't get rid of without breaking the whole plugin. Thank you for sharing, though! This could be handy in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very quick example to get you on the right track, providing you don't opt for a plugin:

http://jsfiddle.net/22VNQ/1/

Note: Additionally please up-vote and mark answers as correct. It appears you haven't done this for previous answers, hence the lack of response.

Comment: Upvotes apparently require 15 rep, and my previous two questions only yielded one answer that did not help me.

This you have suggested is a good start, I will see what I can do with this. Thank you!

ADDITIONALLY: My navigation is not within the .page slides, it is hovering above them so that the slides my move beneath the navigation.

Comment: @bo1g Apologies, I forgot about the workings of the reward system. In this case all you would need to do is adjust the margin of the active page, which could be identified through setting a class.

Comment: I'll keep fiddling with it, but this looks like the route I'll be taking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use Slideshow specific javascripts like -

**Impress.js** : https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/wiki/Examples-and-demos

**Deck.js** : http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/

**Reveal.js** : https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js